# Alloy model of the Einstein puzzle

Tags: alloy

[**Update**] Thanks to the excellent insights by @Daniel Jackson and @Peter Kriens I fixed my Alloy model. Now the Alloy Analyzer generates one instance. I wrote up this problem and I show the solution. I show for each of the 5 houses the color, nationality, drink, cigarette, and pet. By the way, it is the German who keeps fish. [Here](http://xfront.com/Alloy/Einstein-Puzzle.docx) is my write-up.

I created an Alloy model of the Einstein puzzle. See below. When I ran my model, the Alloy Analyzer found several instances. I thought there would be only one instance (one solution). This makes me wonder if my model is correct. Do you see a problem with my model? Should there be only one solution to the Einstein puzzle?

Here is the Einstein puzzle:

There are five houses of different colors next to each other on the same road. In each house lives a man of a different nationality. Every man has his favorite drink, his favorite brand of cigarettes, and keeps pets of a particular kind. Here are the constraints:

```
1.  The Englishman lives in the red house.
2.  The Swede keeps dogs.
3.  The Dane drinks tea.
4.  The green house is just to the left of the white one.
5.  The owner of the green house drinks coffee.
6.  The Pall Mall smoker keeps birds.
7.  The owner of the yellow house smokes Dunhills.
8.  The man in the center house drinks milk.
9.  The Norwegian lives in the first house.
10. The Blend smoker has a neighbor who keeps cats.
11. The man who smokes Blue Masters drinks beer.
12. The man who keeps horses lives next to the Dunhill smoker.
13. The German smokes Prince.
14. The Norwegian lives next to the blue house.
15. The Blend smoker has a neighbor who drinks water.
```

The question to be answered is: **Who keeps fish?**

Here is my Alloy model:

```
open util/ordering[House]

sig House {
    color: Color,
    nationality: Nationality,
    drink: Drink,
    cigarette: Cigarette,
    pet: Pet
}

abstract sig Color {}
one sig red extends Color {}
one sig green extends Color {}
one sig yellow extends Color {}
one sig blue extends Color {}
one sig white extends Color {}

abstract sig Nationality {}
one sig Englishman extends Nationality {}
one sig Swede extends Nationality {}
one sig Dane extends Nationality {}
one sig German extends Nationality {}
one sig Norwegian extends Nationality {}

abstract sig Drink {}
one sig tea extends Drink {}
one sig coffee extends Drink {}
one sig milk extends Drink {}
one sig beer extends Drink {}
one sig water extends Drink {}

abstract sig Cigarette {}
one sig Pall_Mall extends Cigarette {}
one sig Dunhills extends Cigarette {}
one sig Blend extends Cigarette {}
one sig Blue_Masters extends Cigarette {}
one sig Prince extends Cigarette {}

abstract sig Pet {}
one sig dog extends Pet {}
one sig bird extends Pet {}
one sig horse extends Pet {}
one sig cat extends Pet {}
one sig fish extends Pet {}

fact {
    some disj h1, h2, h3, h4, h5: House | h1.color = red and h2.color = green and h3.color = yellow and h4.color = blue and h5.color = white
    no disj h,h': House | h.nationality = h'.nationality
    some h: House | (h.nationality = Englishman) and (h.color = red)
    some h: House | (h.nationality = Swede) and (h.pet = dog)
    some disj h, h': House | (h.color = green) and (h'.color = white) and (h'.prev = h)
    some h: House | (h.color = green) and (h.drink = coffee)
    some h: House | (h.cigarette = Pall_Mall) and (h.pet = bird)
    some h: House | (h.color = yellow) and (h.cigarette = Dunhills)
    some h: House | (some h.prev.prev) and (some h.next.next) and (h.drink = milk)
    some h: House | (h = first) and (h.nationality = Norwegian)
    some h: House | (h.cigarette = Blue_Masters) and (h.drink = beer)
    some disj h,h': House | (h.pet = horse) and (h'.cigarette = Dunhills) and ((h.next = h') or (h.prev = h'))
    some h: House | (h.nationality = German) and (h.cigarette = Prince)
    some disj h,h': House | (h.nationality = Norwegian) and (h'.color= blue) and (h.next = h')
    some disj h,h': House | (h.cigarette = Blend) and (h'.drink = water) and (h.next = h')
}

pred Who_keeps_fish {
    some h: House | h.pet = fish
}

run Who_keeps_fish for 5
```

Comment: Any reason why you do not use `enum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle) is supposed to have a unique solution. 
I would not be surprised to find multiple instances, though, due to incomplete symmetry breaking. What is more surprising (and suggests to me a problem with your model) is that the first instance generated has both the Norwegian and the German keeping fish. Looks as if you need to add the constraint that the occupants of the houses keep different pets (ie, the pet relation is injective).

Answer (score 1):

I think the text of your code deviates too much from the original definition. In my experience when you have to follow an existing spec it is crucial to express the text as literal as possible in Alloy. I.e. you fit the model so that the vocabulary matches the original spec (puzzle).

In this case the house seems to be the central point of reasoning. So I created a House atom that holds the different properties. I named the fields so they match the words in the descriptions. I then used the ~ to get the proper word order. I.e. 'the Englishman lives' becomes 'Englishman.~lives' or 'lives.Englishman'. I find this strategy quite crucial to work with Alloy (or any formal language). The onus to verify should be on the underlying model not on my brain trying to interpret math symbols. I think this is a similar approach as creating a DSL.

I then got one solution with the following model:

```
open util/ordering[House]

enum Color { red, green, yellow, blue, white}
enum Nationality { Englishman, Swede, Dane, German, Norwegian}
enum Drink { tea, coffee, milk, beer, water}
enum Cigarette {Pall_Mall, Dunhills, Blend, Blue_Masters, Prince}
enum Pet { dogs, birds, horses, cats, fish }

sig House {
    colored  : disj Color,
    lives    : disj Nationality,
    drinks   : disj Drink,
    smoker   : disj Cigarette,
    keeps    : disj Pet
} 

pred House.hasNeighbourWho[ other : House ] { 
    other in this.(prev+next) 
}

let centerHouse = first.next.next

fact {
    // 1.  The Englishman lives in the red house.
    Englishman.~lives in colored.red

    // 2.  The Swede keeps dogs.
    Swede.~lives in keeps.dogs

    // 3.  The Dane drinks tea.
    Dane.~lives in drinks.tea

    // 4.  The green house is just to the left of the white one.
    green.~colored = colored.white.prev

    // 5.  The owner of the green house drinks coffee.
    green.~colored = drinks.coffee

    // 6.  The Pall Mall smoker keeps birds.
    Pall_Mall.~smoker = keeps.birds

    // 7.  The owner of the yellow house smokes Dunhills.
    yellow.~colored = smoker.Dunhills

    // 8.  The man in the center house drinks milk.
    centerHouse = drinks.milk

    // 9.  The Norwegian lives in the first house.
    Norwegian.~lives  = first

    // 10. The Blend smoker has a neighbor who keeps cats.
    Blend.~smoker.hasNeighbourWho[ keeps.cats ] 

    // 11. The man who smokes Blue Masters drinks beer.
    Blue_Masters.~smoker = drinks.beer

    // 12. The man who keeps horses lives next to the Dunhill smoker.
    keeps.horses.hasNeighbourWho[smoker.Dunhills]

    // 13. The German smokes Prince.
    German.~lives = smoker.Prince

    // 14. The Norwegian lives next to the blue house.
    Norwegian.~lives.hasNeighbourWho[colored.blue]

    // 15. The Blend smoker has a neighbor who drinks water.
    Blend.~smoker.hasNeighbourWho[drinks.water]
}
pred solution[ p : House ] {
     p = keeps.fish
}
run solution for 5 but exactly 5 House
```

**Updated** Removed meta stuff and used `disj` instead

Answer (score 0):

The original solution seems to miss the constraints that no owners have the same pet, cigarette and drink.

```
    no disj h,h': House | h.pet = h'.pet // otherwise there are solutions with green and white house having both dog as pet
    no disj h,h': House | h.cigarette = h'.cigarette // not really required
    no disj h,h': House | h.drink = h'.drink // not really required
```

Without these, as noted above, you get illegal solutions.
[Here is a rendering constructed with ProB showing an illegal solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDNh9.png)

After correction, you [get this solution with ProB (using Alloy2B and VisB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh0Oj.png):
(see [here](https://gitlab.cs.uni-duesseldorf.de/general/stups/visb-visualisation-examples/-/tree/master/Einstein) if you are interested in the visualization)